# Custom typed, non-generic, read-only, fixed-sized collection class in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking for suggestions on how to create a custom collection class in VB.Net, to contain instances of a custom object class. There is so much information on the topic that I'm not sure which direction to go in, and custom collections are new to me.

The collection needs are as follows:

- collection should be read-only, it and its objects cannot be modified.
- collection will always be a fixed size.
- because of above two items, add, remove, count, clear, etc aren't needed.
- will create & manage all object instances itself at instantiation.
- should have a default property like "Item". (?)
- should be enumerable, so For-Each can be used on it.

Here is a simplified outline of what I've pieced together so far:

```
Class Bay

    Private ID As Integer
    Private p_String As String
    Private p_Aisle As Integer
    ...etc...

    ...getters, setters, & subs...

End Class

Class Bays

    Inherits ...something...
    Implements ....somethingelse... (?)

    Public ReadOnly MyCollection(5094) as SomeCollectionType (Of Bay)

    Private LastUpdate As Date
    Private SystemStatus as Integer

    Public Sub New()
        ...instantiate all objects in collection...
    End Sub

    ...properties...

End Class
```

Comment: So you don't need a collection, you just need a class with some private variables that only have `Property Get` methods?

Comment: You should look at inheriting the `ReadOnlyCollection(Of T)` class.  You simply fix `T` when you declare the class rather than when you instantiate it.  By the way, you can't prevent the items being modified.  If the items are of a reference type then retrieving an item from the collection gets a reference to the actual object in the collection.  Unless that type is immutable, that object can be modified after retrieval.

Comment: @MacroMan, the type must be able to be fed to a `For Each` loop so, at the very least, it must implement `IEnumerable`. It depends on your definition as to whether that constitutes a collection or not. The type is also supposed to have a default `Item` property, so that sounds awfully like it needs to implement `IList` too.  That's definitely a collection.

Comment: @jmcilhinney would an ArrayList not suffice for this? Admittedly I think I'm struggling to understand what the actual end-purpose of this custom "collection" is and so it's certainly harder to follow the logic.

Comment: Seems more like some kind of (enumerable) factory rather than a collection per-se

Comment: @MacroMan, an `ArrayList` is not read-only and will accept items of any type.  This collection needs to be read-only and accept items of only one specific type.  Not only that, no one without a horse and buggy should be using an `ArrayList` anymore anyway.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Okay, I'll drop out at this point as I'm just not getting the concept of what's needed. FWIW though, I quite enjoy using array lists!

Comment: @Everyone. Hello, sorry to not respond more quickly. The purpose of my custom class and collection are to represent shipping-pallets of products in an automated robotic warehouse. Counting all aisles, rows, and levels, there are 5094 bays where the robots slide pallets into.The database that the system runs on is very old, but it works: Windows 2000 and SQL Server 2000. But also...it's slow.

Comment: The application that I'm writing is an isometric 3D stacked-cubes display to represent bay status and product locations in the warehouse. I need the data instantly available for screen refreshes, and that's not going to happen with that old SQL server, or even a local data cache in an MDB. So it seemed the best option was to store all the info in memory in an array. But...there's a lot of data & metadata, so I decided to create a custom object class, and a collection to put them in, and accept the slight performance hit for the sake of versatility.

Comment: And for the sake of buttoning everything up nicely, I decided to try making it read-only and only exposing what is needed to the parent - which is not much. The parent can look at the data, but not change any of it. But can activate a refresh method, and a couple others.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of thing you can do:

```
Public Class Thing

    '...

End Class


Public Class ReadOnlyThingCollection
    Inherits ReadOnlyCollection(Of Thing)

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(GetItems())
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function GetItems() As IList(Of Thing)
        'Generate items as appropriate.
        Return {New Thing, New Thing, New Thing}
    End Function

End Class
```